I can't run jest snapshot tests because im constantly getting the ''Warning: Invalid hook call."
My components are working correctly, but I need to build snapshot tests for my react project, and I can't because of this error.
My data tests are running correctly.
Login.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setAuthedUser } from '../../actions/authedUser';
import UserSelect from '../UserSelect';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Login.css';

function Login() {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState('');
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = () => {
    if (selectedUser) {
      dispatch(setAuthedUser(selectedUser));
      navigate('/dashboard')
    } else {
      alert('Please, select an user.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <p>Select an user to continue:</p>
      <UserSelect users={users} onSelect={setSelectedUser} />
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Enter</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

Login.test.js
import React from "react";
import Login from "../components/Login/Login";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../store/store";

test ('the component renders correctly', () => {
  const {asFragment} = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Login/>
    </Provider>
  );

  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
});

My github repository.
THE FULL ERROR:




I'm trying to build a snapshot test where it verify the login components are ok.
I tried to reinstall the node_modules and didn't work.
Also tried to search for multiple versions and not compatible versions.

Your unit test is missing providing a routing context for the useNavigate hook call in the Login component you are testing.
Update the unit test to provide all contexts/etc the unit under test needs. Ensure you have properly installed all project dependencies in the correct directory, e.g. the project root.

Provider provides the Redux context for the useDispatch and useSelector hooks
MemoryRouter provides the routing context for the useNavigate hook

Example:
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import Login from "../components/Login/Login";
import store from "../store/store";

test('the component renders correctly', () => {
  const { asFragment } = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Login />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
});

It's common to extract the providers into a wrapper function used by React-Testing-Library's render function.
Basic Example:
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import store from "../store/store";

export const TestProviders = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MemoryRouter>
      {children}
    </MemoryRouter>
  </Provider>
);

import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import Login from "../components/Login/Login";
import { TestProviders } from "../path/to/TestProviders";

test('the component renders correctly', () => {
  const { asFragment } = render(<Login />, { wrapper: TestProviders});

  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
});

